# Writing new line character in Java that works across different OS

Tags: java, unix, solaris, newline

I have a Java program which generates a text file on a UNIX server. This text file is then sent to a customer's machine using other systems where it is supposed to be opened in notepad on Windows. As we are well aware that notepad will not be able to find a new line as it uses Windows CR LF.

I am using

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Is there another way of acheiving platform independece so that a file generated on UNIX can be displayed in Windows notepad with the proper formatting like changing some UNIX property for new line?

Notepad is a pre-requisite, hence changing that is not possible.

Comment: The property 'line.separator' will be the line separator *on the server*. The file is the file is the file. If you want to edit it in Notepad, use CR LF.

Comment: It seems like your question is self-contrary. You need a way to specify platform-independent line separator, but you by youself agree, what line separator is different on different platforms :) If you need correct l-s on windows -- you should explicitly write CR LF. Although, doesn't current versions of notepad recognize unix-style line separators?

Comment: Using CR LF will cause the file to be displayed with extra character at the end of line (the CR character) in UNIX because UNIX only uses LF for new line. This causes problems when using the report on UNIX based systems as there are some points in the workflow where uses will use VI, and MAC systems to use the report

Comment: @BegemoT: that is my exact problem :) I am using line seperator and encountering this issue. I am asking for an alternative for the same :)

Comment: if your unix reporting and windows notepad use different l-s -- there is no way you can deal with it but to have some conversion software between. Current VCS (SVN, e.g.) can automatically convert l-s -- just for example

Comment: agreed. then will have to make two copies of the same file one that can be used on WIndows and one on UNIX? but that created issues with maintaining them. this problem is an ouch :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You need to pick a single file format, Windows or UNIX. Given that your customer requires notepad, you can probably pick Windows format, which means you just need "\r\n" characters. The fact that UNIX generates the file can be considered irrelevant.

Comment: check my comment number 3 , hence cannot use CR LF

Comment: You're basically stuck then :-) No chance your customer can use a UNIX-friendly editor such as Textpad?  How about generate two files, one with UNIX format, one with Windows?  Hopefully by now you do understand the fundamental problem with the two different formats, and there is no single dual-compatible newline option available to you?

Comment: I was hoping a dual compatible newline option has come up since the time I had learned about new lines. but it hasn't. Will probably have to force the user to use notepad as it comes pre installed. Other editors might incur licence costs to the customer (Problems with corporates :) When will they start using open-source apart from JAVA)

Comment: there are dozens of free text editors about, just google them I am sure you will find some good candidates?  alternatively - have you thought of generating CSV reports, and your customers can use, e.g. Excel to read them? eliminates the CR/LF issue of text files

Comment: Yes I am using a CSV report and there is a TXT report. CSV is fine in excel :) TXT is what is creating the problems. As for the free editors, organisation does not allow any software that comes without support :D

Comment: Tough one :-)  I think you *need* to use Windows format for your text file then. Customer requirement comes first. For UNIX work, you can use the command dos2unix to convert your file for use there, or look into other workarounds, but fundamentally it seems you have no choice but to use CR/LF for good Notepad display.

Answer (score 7):

**Since Java 7** `System.lineSeparator()` ..

Java APIs keep changing with time. Writing new line character in Java that works across different OS could be achieved with `System.lineSeparator()` API which has been there since Java 7.  check this,
[System.lineSeperator()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--)

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X supports CR, LF and CRLF
Linux uses LF, but files using CRLF and CR render too.
Windows uses CRLF

the answer: just always use CRLF, then you have support for all platforms.

CR = '\r' , LF='\n'

so just make strings of the format : "mytexthereblahblahblah \r\n"

Comment: but that will cause a problem for the file to be viewed on unix?

Comment: most unixes and *nixes (BSD, Darwin, Linux) use the same tools and editors etc. I don't think it will cause trouble unless you're using some ancient unix from 1979 :)

Comment: its Solaris. it wont throw any errors but it will display unncessary extra characters (the CR that is; as the LF will be interpreted as a new line)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

This is wrong. You don't care what the system's line separator is. You need to write out a file in the format that *file* is supposed to be in. It doesn't matter what system generates the file.

A file is a stream of bytes. You need to write out the stream of bytes that the file format says you should be writing, and that is independent of what line separate any system uses.

Comment: agreed. But what if the file is to be viewed on multiple systems?

Comment: The whole point of file formats is to permit files to be moved from system to system without compatibility problems. If you write in the file what the file format calls for, the file will be portable. You're writing something that's system-specific into a file, that's pretty much *always* broken behavior. (Except in the rare case where the file is not supposed to be portable.)

Comment: Okay, and are you converting line endings when exporting the files or not? If you are, use local system-style line endings. If not, use CRLF.

Comment: i use System.getProperty which gives me system style line endings which are basically Unix as it runs on Solaris. It seems there is no way to make it interoperable will have to convince the folks to use notepad compulsorily :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the UNIX server can tolerate Windows style newlines?  Since the requirement is editting in Notepad, you will need to put Windows style newlines in the file using `System.print("\r\n")`.

If the UNIX server can't handle Windows line separators, then your best option is probably to process the file after editting to convert the newlines using [dos2unix](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) on the UNIX server.

The Notepad requirement means that this isn't really a platform independence requirement - it's a requirement for the Unix server to understand Windows newlines.

Comment: right. that can be done but its similar to having hard code CRLF. that is what UNIX is not ready to read.

Comment: It's all about meeting the requirements / constraints.  If the file must be editted in Notepad, it must contain CRLF.  If it must be read be a UNIX process that cannot tolerate CRLF, then they must be converted.

Comment: yep. but it can be used on both and that is where I am getting stuck.!! but notepad does have higher priority

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way for having such interoperable simple text file. Hence will have to move to a structured file like doc or excel or pdf or simply fix the format to either windows or UNIX and communicate the end users to use the same.

This answer is an aggregate of the above discussion.

Thanks a lot community for helping. If any other solution is found to the problem. Please post for others :)